# Custom handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have function which return JSON:

```
  Template.mainmenu.menuitem = function() {
    var jsonObj = { items: [
        { url: "http://google.com", title: "google" },
        { url: "http://stackoverflow.com", title: "stackoverflow" },
      ] };

    return jsonObj;
  };
```

And I have custom handlebars helper:

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('woodoo', function(context, options) {
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0, j = context.length; i < j; i++) {      
      ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
      alert(ret);
    }

    return ret;
  });
```

This is template:

```
<template name="mainmenu">
  {{#woodoo menuitem}}
    <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
  {{/woodoo}}
```

HTML page is rendering without error, but I can not see urls and I don't have any alert message.  Why and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, in your handlebars helper function, `context.length` would return `undefined`, so there would be nothing to alert.

You'd want your for loop to stop at the length of the keys within the `items` key.  A short way to write that would be `Object.keys(context.items).length`.  Similarly, the keys you need to iterate over are in `context.items`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('woodoo', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";
  for(var i = 0, j = Object.keys(context.items).length; i < j; i++) {
    ret = ret + options.fn(context.items[i]);
  alert(ret);
}
  return ret;
});
```

Comment: RE: browser compatibility, `Object.keys` is not available in IE below 9.  Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_support

Answer (score 1):

Given the Template.mainmenu.menuitem function you listed, you don't need a custom Handlebars helper.  You can use the built-in #each helper like so:

```
<template name="mainmenu">
  {{#each menuitem.items}}
    <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```